# How can I determine UITabBarItem position?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitabbarcontroller, uitabbar

How can I determine if a UITabBarItem has the title "Hello" and is in position 0?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `items` property of the UITabBar, like:

```
if([[myTabBar items] indexOfObject:myTabBarItem] == 0)
{
  UITabBarItem* theItem = [[myTabBar items] objectAtIndex:0];

  if([theItem.title isEqualToString:@"Hello"])
  {
    // it's in position 0 and has title "Hello"
  }
}
```

Comment: I wouldn't recommend looking at the title, especially if you're using things like string localization. Instead, use the tag for this purpose, and define a range of integer values which represent your tabs, define some constants to make your code more readable for when you come back to it in the future, and compare on the tag.

Answer (score 2):

I'd rather get the index of the item using `indexOfObject` on the `tabBar` items array:

```
NSUInteger index = [tabBar.items indexOfObject:item];
```

Answer (score 0):

uitabbaritem inherits from uibaritem which defines the tag and title properties.